# Python web crawler multithreading and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, web-crawler

Briefly idea, My web crawler have 2 main jobs. Collector and Crawler, The collector will collecting all of the url items for each sites and storing non duplicated url. The crawler will grab the urls from storage, extract needed data and store its back.

> 2 Machines
>
> 1. Bot machine -> 8 core, Physical Linux OS (No VM on this machine)
> 2. Storage machine -> mySql with clustering (VM for clustering), 2 databases (url and data); url database on port 1 and data port 2

Objective: Crawled 100 sites and try to decrease the bottle neck situation

> First case: Collector *request(urllib) all sites , collect the url
>   items for each sites and * insert if it's non duplicated url to
>   Storage machine on port 1. Crawler *get the url from storage port 1 ,
>   *request site and extract needed data and *store it's back on port 2

This cause the connection bottle neck for both request web sites and mySql connection

> Second case: Instead of inserting across the machine, Collector store
>   the url on my own mini database file system.There is no *read a huge
>   file(use os command technic) just *write (append) and *remove header
>   of the file.

This cause the connection request web sites and I/O (read,write) bottle neck (may be)

Both case also have the CPU bound cause of collecting and crawling 100 sites

As I heard for I/O bound use multithreading, CPU bound use multiprocessing

How about both ? scrappy ? any idea or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into grequests, it doesn't do actual muti-threading or multiprocessing, but it scales much better than both.

Comment: Note, you can also use urlopen with gevent if you don't want to change the api you use to do the actual crawling

Comment: With out multiprocessing or multithreading, It's seem to run collector 100 times and crawler 100 times (Handle with fabric). The problem is Python didn't handle the processes but the OS. So the CPU scheduling was really wired. It's take turn between the processes handling by Operating System